# Glossaries do not show up

Tags: glossaries

I am encountering some difficulties with glossaries, maybe one of you has a good idea how to fix it.
Following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[    nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
%Symbolverzeichnis
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
%Indexverzeichnis
\newglossary[ilg]{indizes}{ini}{ing}{Indizes}
%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

%Verzeichnisstil mit Einheit
\newglossarystyle{fz}{%  
 % Verzeichnis wird ein 'longtable'  mit 3 Spalten
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
  {\begin{longtable}{p{3.4cm}p{3cm}p{9.6cm}}}%  
  {\end{longtable}}%  
 % Kopf der Tabelle
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  
 \textbf{Formelzeichen} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Bedeutung}%
  \\\endhead}%  
 % Kein Abstand zwischen Gruppen 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
    %    
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%  
    \glstarget{##1}{##4}% Symbol 
        & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Einheit
        & ##3% Beschreibung  
  }% 
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\relax}
}
%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{cae}{CAE}{Computer Aided Engineering} \gls{cae}
\newglossaryentry{$T_{Ent}$}{name=Entformungstemperatur,description={Solltemperatur zum Entformungszeitpunkt},symbol={$T_{Ent}$},type=symbolslist,user1={\textcelsius}} \gls{$T_{Ent}$}
\newglossaryentry{$Ent$}{name=Entformung,description={Entformung},type=indizes} \gls{$Ent$}



%Glossare
\subsection{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
%Abkürzungen ausgeben
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\subsection{Formelzeichen}
%Symbole ausgeben
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=fz]
\subsection{Indizes}
%Glossar ausgeben
\printglossary[type=indizes,style=fz]

\end{document}
```

I compile by using:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
makeindex -s %.ist -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn|
makeindex -s %.ist -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo|
makeindex -s %.ist -t %.slg -o %.syi %.syg|
makeindex -s %.ist -t %.ilg -o %.ini %.ing|
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|
evince %.pdf
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

No glossary is printed, why? Also I noticed not all logs (e.g. alg is missing) and the makeindex calls nomencl.ist e.g. for the indizes glossary. What is my mistake? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rather use the `makeglossaries` script, bunches of `makeindex` commands, i.e. in a shell (say bash): `pdflatex foo  ; makeglossaries foo ; pdflatex foo` if your document is called `foo.tex`. You should also add `nomain` to the `glossaries` option list (but that is unrelated actually).

Comment: Alternatively use `\makenoidxglossaries` instead of `\makeglossaries`

Comment: Thanks that did it! Pretty easy, but I misleadingly thought only `makeindex` is possible.

Comment: See also the `Introduction` section in `glossaries-user.pdf`, please

Comment: @ChristianHupfer an answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: I am pretty sure this is a duplicate, but answered ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer +1 anyway ... perhaps you could mention `arara`? disclaimer: i'm an `arara` fanboy :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I am a fan of Paulo as well but 'never' used 'arara' so far -- don't tell him :D

Comment: I recommend you also [move your `\newacronym` and `\newglossaryentry` commands to the preamble](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running bunches of `makeindex` commands on the various output files for each glossary type, use the makeglossaries script instead, i.e.

(Assuming pdflatex as binary and a filename of `foo.tex`)

> pdflatex foo
>
> makeglossaries foo
>
> pdflatex foo

Normally this should provide the glossary as desired, perhaps a 3rd run of `pdflatex` is needed, depending on special setups.

Alternatively use `\makenoidxglossaries` instead of `\makeglossaries`.

Off-topic: `glossaries` complains about the fact that there is no main glossary (the default one), so use `\usepackage[nomain,...]{glossaries}` rather here. (The `...` represent possible other options here, omitted for sake of shortness